# Slow UPDATE statements in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mysqli

I recently moved my website to another server and when i run a script that makes a lot of `UPDATE` statements i see very slowly results.

OLD_SERVER : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650L 0 @ 1.80GHz with 8 cores and 1.500 MB RAM

SERVER : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz 8 cores and 32GB RAM + 2 ssd in RAID ( 10x times better then the old)

**** php script code ****

```
$startTime = microtime(true);  

// change this with a mysql query           
$update_result = mysql_query("
UPDATE some_table 
SET order_id = ".$random_order_id."
WHERE id = ".$row_get['id']."
");

// Your content to test
$endTime = microtime(true);  
$elapsed = $endTime - $startTime;
echo "Execution time : $elapsed seconds\n";

if(!$update_result)
{
    return array(
    "result" => false,
    "code" => 502,
    "reason" => "SQL Update error"
    );
}
```

**** OLD_SERVER script output (very fast): ****

```
306497 will have order_id = 49438<br/>
Execution time : 0.00071907043457031 seconds
306505 will have order_id = 113556<br/>
Execution time : 0.00055885314941406 seconds
306508 will have order_id = 295573<br/>
Execution time : 0.00074100494384766 seconds
306511 will have order_id = 206028<br/>
Execution time : 0.00042295455932617 seconds
306518 will have order_id = 241993<br/>
Execution time : 0.00048589706420898 seconds

iotop renders 10MB/sec
```

**** NEW_SERVER script output (very slow): ****

```
10995 will have order_id = 94532<br/>
Execution time : 0.030339956283569 seconds
11021 will have order_id = 158848<br/>
Execution time : 0.060288906097412 seconds
11035 will have order_id = 288621<br/>
Execution time : 0.030526876449585 seconds
11059 will have order_id = 194945<br/>
Execution time : 0.031852960586548 seconds
11089 will have order_id = 176289<br/>
Execution time : 0.030807018280029 seconds
11102 will have order_id = 80207<br/>
Execution time : 0.059854984283447 seconds
11147 will have order_id = 33899<br/>
Execution time : 0.030609846115112 seconds
11392 will have order_id = 124314<br/>
Execution time : 0.031843900680542 seconds
11541 will have order_id = 249986<br/>

iotop renders 300KB/sec
```

**** /etc/mysql/my.cnf ****

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
#bind-address       = 148.251.126.39
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#

query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 256M

# query_cache_size=0

#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/


innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_io_capacity = 20000
innodb_read_io_threads = 5000
innodb_write_io_threads = 5000
```

Where is the problem ?? I don't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: After you moved the servers. You create all indexes?

Comment: What does the rest of the stack look like. Apache/Nginix? All components on same machine? Anything in error logs?

Comment: have you considered transactions

Comment: You don't explain what the storage system in the old server is, just that the new server has SSD's. But given the speed differences, you're probably looking at SSD v.s. spinning platters, and this is a total non-issue. Plus, how do could you possibly get 1.5meg of ram in a modern Xeon-based system?

Comment: @Jorge Campos i tought that this may be a problem ... how to do that?

Comment: When I say server I was talking about your database. If you did not import it properly you may not have created all indexes for that table. So You should check on your old database which indexes were on it then recreate it on the new database server.

Comment: @Jordan same machine, same soft, i only suspect the mysql config or SSD write on disc ...

Comment: @Marc B old server is virtualized and it is just an 7200 RPM HDD ..., but the ideea is that the NEW SERVER is 10x faster ... still, slower speed ...

Comment: @Damian: then maybe you should fix up your text, because you've got both speedtest runs labelled "old server".

Comment: "So You should check on your old database which indexes were on it then recreate it on the new database server. " -> i imported it from a `mysqldump` command, is there is a way to recreate indexes ?

Comment: my bad ... i have change it ... ok but the question remains, do i have to rebuild indexes? i just imported from `mysqldump` to be onest ...

Comment: anyone? need an answer ...

Comment: anyone? need an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

Please check for the indexes first,
use

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM some_table;
```

on both the servers, and check whether there is any index on field 'id' in the old server. 
Clearly you have upgraded your server configurations, so the issue must be in replication.

Comment: i think the index are still creating for some reason, see here proof : http://pastebin.com/Pc8TGspD